An Absurd Comedy Movie About Religion
I am trying to find a comedy movie about religion:  

(A) There was a priest who died,  
(B) There was another priest who trying to be done (A's) his last will  
B finally found himself in a post-production studio which dubbing for porn movies; it seems priest A was occasionally dubbing for porns secretly.  
There was a man who became apparently Jesus after a few personal life disaster.
As I remember it was late 80s or 90s, I think it was a European movie, maybe Italian


Is it possibly "Adamsäpfel" ? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0418455/

@FlorianNeiss not so close, but it looks like worth to watch, thank you!

It looks like The Favour, the Watch and the Very Big Fish (1991):

A farce, Hoskins plays a photographer who specializes in religious
  pictures who searches for a model for Jesus. He does a favor for a
  friend and finds himself doing a voice track for a porno movie with
  Natasha Richardson. Hoskins finds his model for Jesus in Jeff Goldblum
  and a romantic triangle begins in which Goldblum finds adoring crowds
  believing him to be Jesus and then begins to believe it himself.

